# R: randomly subset rows within each level in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
name           category
sam_yell3_1     yellow
sam_yell3_2     yellow
sam_yell4_10    yellow
sam_blk1_5      black
sam_blk2_2      black
sam_pur1_7      purple
sam_pur1_9      purple
sam_pur1_13     purple
sam_pur5_22     purple
sam_pur5_53     purple
```

I want to randomly subset rows in `df` without replacement into three new dataframes, so that values in `df$name` within each level of `df$category` are randomly distributed among each new dataframe. I also want to make sure that every level of category is represented within each new dataframe (assuming there are at least three rows corresponding with each category). Using this example, the result might look something like this:

New `df1`:

```
sam_yell3_1     yellow
sam_blk1_5      black
sam_pur1_7      purple
```

New `df2`:

```
sam_yell4_10    yellow
sam_pur1_9      purple
sam_pur5_22     purple
```

New `df3`:

```
sam_yell3_2     yellow
sam_blk2_2      black
sam_pur5_53     purple
```

Is there a way to do this in R? In reality I have thousands of rows in `df` and hundreds of levels in `df$category`, with an uneven number of values for `df$name` corresponding with each level of `df$category`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Must they have equal number of rows? ie 3 or can one of then have 4?

Comment: @Onyambu the rows can be unequal if they have to. I'd like to keep as balanced as possible but know that won't always be possible for levels with a number of rows that isn't a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
n <- nrow(df)
groups <- 3
df_list <- split(df[sample(n),], rep(seq(groups), n, n))
df_list

$`1`
         name category
5  sam_blk2_2    black
7  sam_pur1_9   purple
9 sam_pur5_22   purple
2 sam_yell3_2   yellow

$`2`
           name category
10  sam_pur5_53   purple
3  sam_yell4_10   yellow
1   sam_yell3_1   yellow

$`3`
         name category
8 sam_pur1_13   purple
4  sam_blk1_5    black
6  sam_pur1_7   purple
```

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu! This is nearly the result I'm looking for! Is there a way to ensure that each level is represented within each group? For example, in your solution, is there a way to make sure yellow shows up in each group, not just in groups 1 and 2? This of course assumes there are at least three rows corresponding with each level.

Comment: @nrcombs thats was not originally included in the question. You should consider accepting one of the solutions given here then you can consider asking that as a new question

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to my question using the `partition` function from the package `groupdata2`:

```
partition(df, p=c(0.33, 0.33), cat_col= "category", force_equal=FALSE, list_out=TRUE)
```

This partitions rows among three nearly balanced groups, making sure each level of `df$category` is represented within each group. May still be a better way out there but wanted to share in case other users find this solution helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can randomly assign 3 groups for the rows in the dataframe and then use `split` to get them as separate dataframes.

```
df$group <- sample(3, nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
list_df <- split(df, df$group)
```